# How to print file details in C without using ls -ln

Tags: c, linux, file, time, ls

After I found a file on the disk , I now need to print out all its details , for example :

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 1000 1000 8296 2010-01-06 22:29 ./Documents/exer4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 1000 1000 8517 2009-12-30 11:30 ./Documents/os/exer4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 1000 1000 8 2010-01-10 13:10 ./Documents/cs/2012/exer4 -> ../a.out
```

I need to print a file details without using `ls -ln` .Any idea how to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: You don't want to see the symbolic links listed?

Comment: @Levon: This is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the `stat()` function.

Here's a web page that documents *NIX file functions including `stat()`:

http://rabbit.eng.miami.edu/info/functions/unixio.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function:

```
int lstat(const char *path, struct stat *buf);
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me from the shell.

```
 ls -l | grep -v "\->"
```

It simply filters out any line that has a `->` in it.

Note however, that if you have any files/directories that for some reason have `->` in their names, they will also be filtered out. Having said that, I've never seen that, nor would it be a good idea.

Comment: Of course, this fails to display files with "->" in their name, or files owned by accounts with "->" in their name.

Comment: @Robᵩ That's true of course .. but I've never come across this .. have you? Still, I will add this caveat to my answer, just to be explicit (my answer does say it filters out all lines with -> in them)